# VSIntr - deinstrument file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, instrumentation

my use case is: I want to instrument a dll-file for code coverage analysis using the command line tool VSInstr from Visual Studio 2010, run test cases, deinstrument the file, change to another directory and to the same thing for another file.

Now my problem is that I do not know how to deinstrument the first file, does anybody know how to do that ?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, for the misunderstanding, to make things clearer:
My problem is not that I need to restore the first file, my problem is that VSinstr won't let me instrument a second file for code coverage while another file is instrumented. If I simply delete the instrumented file, as suggested, I get the error "Error VSP1005: Command line error: Instrumenting multiple files is not supported." when I try to instrument another file.

However, it works if I call VSinstr without the command line parameter "Coverage", which I need to use.

Comment: "De-instrument"? Why would you want to do that? Simply make a backup copy of the uninstrumtented DLL before instrumenting it.

Comment: VSinstr won't let me instrument another file, see my edit.

Comment: It seems to be a bug, see [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsprofiler/thread/e21c41b6-3dbf-40c9-8521-2b6d43737703) and specifically the last response from Daryush Laqab

Comment: Thank you for the link, unfortunately it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't solve it. That wasn't it's intention. It was supposed to show you that there seems to be a bug here and not intended behavior. So, "de-instrumenting" won't help, because such functionality doesn't exist in the first place. You need to find a way to work around this bug, not to "de-instrument" your DLL.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "deinstrument" the file - if you didn't specify a new name for the instrumented version, the original version is renamed, so you just have to delete the instrumented DLL and rename the original back. Section of [the VSInstr documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182402%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) copied below

[image: Screenshot]